# Can't select postgresql in libre base

Tags: libreoffice, postgresql

After freshly installing Ubuntu 13.10 (64 bit) and Libre Base 4.1 (using the software center) the selector for PostgreSQL databases is missing. Can't figure out what might be missing. I installed all extensions that are listed in the software center.

[image: PostgreSQL selection missing]

[image]

Comment: While this seems like a legit question, it's not the best place to ask.

Comment: I suggest migration to superuser.

Comment: Moving sounds good. How about askUbuntu?

Comment: askUbuntu sounds good, too. Flag the question and ask for migration to a target of your choice ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql
```

EDIT: You can also search for libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql in the software center.

Comment: It works! How did I miss that package? I would also give you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation ;) Edit: Accepting the answer bumped me up to 15. Let the upvoting begin :)